# Google Visualization: Keep data points visible

Tags: google-visualization

I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the dots visible for each data point on a line chart. The default behavior is that a dot only appears on a data point (along with a tootip) when you hover over it. I'd like the data point dots to be visible by default. Is there a way I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `pointSize` attribute is responsible for the dot size. So something like `chart.draw(data, {pointSize: 1})` should make the points visible by default. (The default setting is size 0.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointSize options. By default its set to 0, that hides the data points. Set it to a value according to the size of the dot that you want. Something like `pointSize: 4` is a good choice.